# How to ssh from shell script and execute for loop using global parameters?

Tags: ssh, scripting, shell

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this.

```
Servers = (11, 12, 13)

ssh -t admin@10.1.1.10 << EOF
    sudo tar -zcf somefolders.tar.gz ~/somefolders
    for i in "${Servers[@]}"
        sudo scp somefolders.tar.gz admin@10.1.1.$i:~
EOF
```

Now the problem is with the `for` loop because it is executed in the remote host without `Servers` parameters and as it was a stand alone command as it should. I know why it is doing it but I don't know how to do this the right way? How can I execute that for loop correctly?

I know one solution is to write the operation multiple times with different ip addresses but we know that is not the efficient way of writing code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: moving the variable declaration `Servers = (11, 12, 13)` inside the ssh block ?

Comment: it will try to execute `Servers` operation but will get a syntax error. That is the main problem. Anything I write after the `<< EOF` it tried to execute it on command line in remote server. Like below,   
`[admin@localhost ~]$ servers = (11, 12, 13)`
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use bash arrays for this, just use a space-separated list of servers:

The `$Server` variable will be loccaly interpreted by your shell, and the script passed to 10.1.1.10 will be sent with "`for i in 11 12 13 ;...`" in its content.

```
Servers="11 12 13"

ssh -t admin@10.1.1.10 << EOF
    sudo tar -zcf somefolders.tar.gz ~/somefolders
    for i in $Servers ;do
        sudo scp somefolders.tar.gz admin@10.1.1.\$i:~
    done
EOF
```